# Node JS PDF Digital Signature using a yubikey

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, certificate, digital-signature

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction?
I need to add a digital signature to a pdf document programmatically because I am using a Yubikey I can't access the private key but I can generate the signature data using the yubico-piv-tool CLI, additionally I have access to the public key, Root and CA pem certificates, my question is can someone help with an example on how to add a signature placeholder, add the signature data and the certificates to the document and save the final document